# How to force a delegate type to not hold any information?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am designing an API that is very comparable to Linq (it's a linq that acts on more complex objects) and I have some client developers who don't quite get the philosophy behind it. I would like to prevent them from doing some things, so that their code is more in line with what the API is all about. So for the examples I will just refer to Linq.

In very short, what I see in the client code is something similar to:

```
IEnumerable<double> xlist;
IEnumerable<double> ylist;
var zlist = xlist.Select( (x,i) => x + ylist.ElementAt(i) );
```

This is really bad, and rather than me having to tell people that they are misbehaving, I would like to force my clients to write this instead:

```
var zlist = xlist.Zip(ylist, (x,y) => x + y);
```

So after thinking about it, I figured that what I would really want for my API, is to prevent clients from "injecting" data into delegate types. In other words, I would like to define extension methods, such as:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> MySelect<TSource, TResult>(
                                this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                StaticFunc<TSource, int, TResult> selector)
```

where StaticFunc would be some kind of delegate type that doesn't hold any data (or at most that would only static-context data).

Can anyone see a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am designing an API that is very comparable to Linq (it's a linq that acts on more complex objects) and I have some client developers who don't quite get the philosophy behind it. I would like to prevent them from doing some things, so that their code is more in line with what the API is all about.

Sounds like what you're really in need of is code review and education, rather than tools. There's certainly nothing within the language to make sure that a developer isn't doing this - and you wouldn't even want to, IMO. For example, your rule would prohibit:

```
public IQueryable<Person> FindUsersByFirstName(string firstName)
{
    return repository.Users.Where(user => user.FirstName == firstName);
}
```

After all, `firstName` is contextual data... but that's perfectly in-keeping with LINQ.

Comment: I understand that the ability to refer to external variables within a lambda expression is extremely useful in many situations. That said, a closed gate is always better than a sign when you want to prevent people from parking their car in your garden.

Comment: @d--b: I have no idea how that analogy is meant to be relevant, but I know that *I* would rather take time to review code and talk to colleagues than try to stop them from doing something harmful in a way which *also* prevents them from doing something *useful* and common. Maybe you should just insist on C# 2 and be done with it... (Not that that would prevent anonymous methods, of course.)

Comment: Ok, I understand that your answer is "there is no way to do this, so you should do code review and education". And that is what I am going to do. I am just asking to see if there is a type within the .Net framework that describes "a delegate that points to a static method" so that I can restrict my users. The ability to constrain what a developer can do against an API is important. It's the same reason why the sealed keyword or List<>.AsReadOnly() exist, isn't it?

Comment: @d--b: No, I'm not saying that. I'm saying that *even if you could do this easily, you shouldn't*. It's simply too restrictive. I entirely agree that it's important to be able to constrain users - but only where that's *sensible*, and I believe you're throwing the baby out with the bathwater here. You could *at execution time* check that there's only one action in a delegate's invocation list, and that it refers to a static method - but that's not a compile-time check, and is basically a bad idea.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll give it some more thoughts then, maybe there are some things I don't fully grasp. Anyways, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) instead of delegates. You will be able to check what is passed in to your code unlike in case of delegates.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I was thinking about compile time rather than runtime.